# Can not install mysql 5.6 using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I am install mysql 5.6 in ubuntu 14.04. I am getting this error.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: mysql-client-5.6 (>=
>   5.6.35-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+0.1)
>
> but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.22-1~) but 5.5.55-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to
>   be installed
>
> Depends: mysql-server-core-5.6 (= 5.6.35-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+0.1)
>   but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you
>   have held broken packages.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> **sudo apt-get install aptitude**
>   **sudo aptitude install mysql-server-core**
>   **sudo aptitude install mysql-common**
>   this will download all the required dependencies for mysql-server

after above commands:

> **sudo apt-get install mysql-server**

this command will install mysql-server.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal type:
    sudo apt-get update

```
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install mysql-common
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-core

sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```